# GeoServer caching

Tags: geoserver

I have a layer group which I want to cache and use in QGIS and ArcMap crs is always epsg:3006.

I've created a gridset with five levels/scales in epsg:3006.

When I add the layer group to **QGIS** the log says:

> Unable to match requested SRS EPSG:4326 to those supported by layer
> http://xxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms

The group layer is working without the gwc (http://xxxxxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/wms).

When added to **ArcMap** the log says:

> 23 001 12:01:00 ERROR  [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request
> failed org.geowebcache.grid.ResolutionMismatchException: Requested
> horizontal resolution: 278.9870178165677 , best match:
> 41.99999999999999 exceeds 10% threshold. Perhaps the client is configured  with an incorrect set of scales (resolutions),  or the DPI
> setting is off compared to the one in GWC ?

and ArcMap says:

> Warning inconsistent extent!

The tile layer previews is working and tiles are being created in the data_dir/gwc folder:
[image]

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: QGis appears to be requesting the tiles in 4326 - are you using WMTS or WMS?

Comment: That will be the problem - use the WMTS endpoint or you are just hoping you hit the right tile origin and scale, most of the time that will not work.

Comment: Changing `http://xxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms` to `http://xxxxxxx:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts` made it work. Is that what you meant?

Comment: that's it - then you are offered a choice of gridsets and image types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure of hitting your cached tiles you need to use the WMTS endpoint rather than the WMS one. QGis will then offer you a choice of projections and image types to use as your layer (I assume the ArcMap can do the same but have never tried it).

Higher dpi is usually resolved by producing larger (512x512) tiles as a 2nd grid set.